# regex match expression to get words between two deliminator (with or without values)

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I have text pattern that may or may not fall between a deliminator.

My pattern is `\| .*? \|` It works when there is text between deliminator `|` eg : `| value1 |` if the value1 is not appearing which is set as empty string say `| |` regex doesn't match.

--GROK filter:
I used \| %{DATA:val} \| for grok filter but it resulted in grok failure.

Comment: I've added answer for you. Is that helped?

Answer (score 1):

How about this without extra spacing characters?

`\|.*?\|`

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/vbLN9L/4/